# Core Data constraint with "includesPropertyValues"

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-data

I would like to make a more efficient fetch on Core Data entities and I have a query.
I want to delete a large amount of records (millions).

My logic is:

1. fetch all records for the entity
2. delete all fetched records.
3. To improve fetching,

I set the following constraint:

```
fetch.includesPropertyValues = NO;
```

My question is: will the relationships (which are kept as properties in the managed objects) also be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you delete a managed object, the relationship delete rules apply regardless of this flag.

With so many records you might also want to want to process the instances in batches. Use `setFetchLimit:` to get a subset of the instances, delete those, save changes, and repeat until no more instances are found.